# Does Windows use internal HDD when write to external USB HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bittorrent

I'm using my external USB HDD to download from torrent because I thought that will not consume my internal HDD.

Then someone told me that the OS, Windows 7 in my case, Write/Read the data to the internal HDD before transferring it to the external USB HDD.

So I wonder is this right ?

Comment: It might but Windows will likely keep any cache to physical memory if it can.  Since we are talking a few hundred MB/sec max because of the throughput of USB it would not only use the physical memory if you literally didn't have enough memory to do so.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a temporary files being used, won't take up much space at all, just do disk cleanup every once in a while.